# Alert on laravel

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel-5

i am trying to upload a text file.i want to give a alert to the user before file get uploaded how many records this file contains(mismatches) which not already  in database.where i am trying to get it by (count > 0).file uploading work fine.but i am struggling with alert.how can i do this.

Here is my code

Controller

```
public function uploadAttendanceFile(Request $request)
{

        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {

            $file = $request->file('file');

            $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $attendanceSheet = new AttendanceSheet();
            $attendanceSheet->name = $name;
            $attendanceSheet->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
            $attendanceSheet->modified_by = Auth::user()->id;
            $attendanceSheet->save();


            $csvMimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain');
            if (!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $csvMimes)) {
                if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {

                    $csvFile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
                    fgetcsv($csvFile);

                    while (($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE) {

                        $date = implode(" ", $line);

                        $x = mb_substr($date, 0, 20);
                        $y = mb_substr($date, 41, 60);
                        $epf = str_replace(' ', '', $x);
                        $fdate = array_filter(explode(" ", $y));

                        /*dd($fdate);*/

                        $a_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fdate[9]));

                        $sql = "SELECT * from attendanceLogs where emp_id ='$epf' AND date ='$a_date' AND time='$fdate[10]' AND session='$fdate[11]'";
                        $result = DB::select(DB::raw($sql));
                        $count = count($result);

                        if ($count > 0) {

                            return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'IT WORKS!');
                        }
                        else {
                            $csv = new AttendanceLogs();

                            $csv->emp_id = $epf;
                            $csv->date = $a_date;
                            $csv->time = $fdate[10];
                            $csv->session = $fdate[11];

                            if (empty($fdate[14])) {
                                $csv->machine = $fdate[15];
                            } elseif (empty($fdate[15])) {
                                $csv->machine = $fdate[14];
                            }

                            $csv->created_by = Auth::user()->id;

                            $csv->save();
                        }

                    }
                }

            }

            $file->move(base_path('public/attendance_sheets'), $file->getClientOriginalName());
            $contents = File::get(base_path('public\attendance_sheets\\' . $name));

        }

    }
```

Blade

```
  <div class="page-content" ng-controller="uploadAttendanceSheetCtrl">
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
        <button type="button"  ng-click = "uploadFile()" id="test" class="btn medium blue" disabled>Upload</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Angular js

```
app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', 'toaster', function ($http, toaster) {

    this.uploadFileToUrl = function (file, uploadUrl) {

            /*toaster.pop('wait', "Uploading");*/

            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', file);
            return $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
            })
                    .success(function () {
                        toaster.clear();
                        toaster.pop('info', "Notificaton", "Attendance Sheet is uploaded successfully", 4000, 'trustedHtml');
                    })
                    .error(function () {
                    });
        }
    }]);

app.controller('uploadAttendanceSheetCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'fileUpload', 'toaster', function ($scope, $http, fileUpload, toaster) {
        $scope.loadUploadedFiles = function () {
            //var year = new Date().getFullYear();
            $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "/attendance/loadUploadedFiles",
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                $scope.uploadedFiles = response.data;

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
            });
        };

        $scope.loadUploadedFiles();


        $scope.uploadFile = function () {

            var file = $scope.attendanceSheet;
            var uploadUrl = "/attendance/uploadAttendanceFile";


            fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl).then(function () {
                $scope.loadUploadedFiles();
            });
        };
}]);
```

Comment: from where you will get 'how many records this file contains(mismatches) which not already in database' do you have some api for this or you have some client side logic for that

Comment: @jitender yep there is some logic.right now as example i have put if ($count > 0) .so what i want is when file meets above condition how can i give a alert to the user.

Comment: I am not sure how laravel works if this work like simple html js than you can use some lib like https://alertifyjs.org/#usage and in uploadFile  function show alert if condition meet